# Django -Display a list of post's categories with a number of post

Tags: python, django

Hi i am trying to make a template in django that displays a post categories table and has a number of posts with it. I can't seem to make it right using annotate when making queries on my model.

like this [image]

views.py

```
categorylistcount = Post.objects.all().annotate(posts_count=Count('category'))
for obj in categorylistcount: 
    print(obj.category + ' : ' + obj.categories_count) #test
```

im receiving list of posts instead and has a posts_count key with value of 1

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    body = models.TextField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=64, default="Uncategorized")
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.author)
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post-detail', kwargs={"pk":  self.pk})
    
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

where did i miss? thanks

Comment: Hi, i think it is `categorylistcount = Post.objects.annotate(posts_count=Count('category'))` instead of `categorylistcount = Post.objects.all().annotate(posts_count=Count('category'))`

Comment: @Luiz nothing changes even if all() is removed.

Answer (score 0):

So with thorough understanding on django docs's model and querysetapi. i have few alterations in my models and how i retrieve the object list

In models.py there was no relation within model Post and model Category, so even if its possible to query a list of categories with the number of post using only Post model, however, its improper not to use the categories model. (i only use it to make options value in my select input on template first)

> Models.py

```
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

having a relation with categories, you can query on categories object and add number of posts using annotate.

```
categories_list = Category.objects.annotate(posts_count=Count('post'))
print(categories_list.values())
```

it is stated in django docs aggregation, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/
hope this helps to someone who's also stuck at making queries